# Opening a QTip2 Modal Window from within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using Qtip2 to create modal window with the code below:

```
$('a#my-link-id').qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('#my-modal-content'),
        title: "My Modal Window Title",
        button: true
    },
    position: {
        my: 'center',
        at: 'center',
        target: $(window)
    },
    show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true,
        modal: {
            on: true
        }
    },
    hide: {
        event: false
    },
    style: 'qtip-modal qtip-shadow'
});
```

This modal will be activated when I click on the link with id `my-link-id`.

However, I want to activate this modal using the `OnClick` feature in a link. So say I have the following link:

```
<a id="my-link-id" href="#" onClick="javascript:getModalWindow('my-link-id');return false;">Fire Modal</a>
```

And I have the following function:

```
window.getModalWindow = function(link_id)
{
    var elem_link = $('a#'+link_id);
    elem_link.qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'my content',
            title: 'My Modal Window Title',
            button: true
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true,
            modal: {
                on: true
            }
        },
        hide: {
            event: false
        },
        style: 'qtip-modal qtip-shadow'
    }).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    elem_link.trigger('click');
    return false;
}
```

The above code does not work as I expect it to. What happens is the click gets triggered continously (not once) until my browser (Chrome) halts it with an 'Aw, Snap!' error. And also the modal does not get activated.

What do I need to do to get this to work?!

Comment: **Why??**  With jQuery, there's no need to use these inline event handlers.  Why not use the `.on('click')` handler you already have in place?

Comment: I need the QTip Modal to fire after some other code processing has been done first so I wasn't able to use the traditional click handler like I have above. Also, the trigger for the `click` event was firing multiple times, not sure why.

Comment: Whatever the cause, it has nothing to do with using a jQuery `.on('click')` instead of an inline  `onClick`.  It's the same event.   It's your code that's different.

Comment: I'd have to show you to whole code set for you to get what I'm saying. Based on my code which is layered somewhat it has everything to do with the click handler, especially the way QTip2 is supposed to work traditionally

Answer (score 0):

I solved this doing what you have below:

```
window._getModalWindow = function(link_id)
{
    var elem_link = $('a#'+link_id);
    var modal_init_bool = elem_link.data('modal_init');
    switch(true)
    {
        case (modal_init_bool !== true):
            elem_link.qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'Modal Window Content',
                    title: 'Modal Window Title',
                    button: true
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'center',
                    at: 'center',
                    target: $(window)
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'modal',
                    solo: true,
                    modal: {
                        on: true
                    }
                },
                hide: {
                    event: false
                },
                style: 'qtip-modal qtip-shadow'
            });
            elem_link.data('modal_init', true);

            break;  
    }

    elem_link.trigger('modal');
    return false;
}
```

I tried using 'click' instead of 'modal' but it just kept firing multiple times when I did that and I don't really understand why.